# What is the best way to iterate input inside a div using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to know (without success), what is the best way to iterate all input element with a specific class in a specific div after a click on a button.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="inputtext">
    <input type="text" class="inputtext">
    <input type="text" class="inputtext">
    <input type="text" class="anotherclass">
    <input type="text" class="anotherclass">
    <button class="full">click me</button>
</div>
```

So i want to get the value of every input with the class inputtext (but not the one with the class anotherclass). I've tried this :

```
$(".full").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).parent().children(".inputtext").val());
});
```

Thanks for your attention !

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map`

```
var values = $(".inputtext").map(function() { return this.value }).get();
```

`values` will be an array of each `input` value.

Comment: Perfect !

So in my case, according to the fact this i only want values of input near to the clicked button, i have to use :

$(this).parent().find(".inputtext").map(function() { return this.value }).get();

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method of JQuery:

```
$(".full").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().children(".inputtext").each(function(){console.log($(this).val());});
});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jx6d4neh/

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$(".full").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".inputtext").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `each()` function, somewhat like this:

```
$(".full").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children(".inputtext").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Or better traverse using `siblings()` instead of `parent().children()` like this

```
$(".full").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".inputtext").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Won't work, the selector is already correct but .val() will only give him the value of the first selected element, he needs to iterate over them.